# How can I update \windows\system32\d3d12sdklayers.dll?

Tags: windows-11, file-permissions, dll

I have some crashes while trying to run DirectX programs that I compile in Visual Studio. It's only when I enable the "debug layer", and I believe it's because my laptop somehow has an out-of-sync version of the file: `C:\windows\system32\d3d12SDKLayers.dll`. I have a better one (I think) from another PC, but when I try to copy it to overwrite the bad one, I get:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> cp 'C:\Users\rob\d3d12SDKLayers.dll' .
cp : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\d3d12SDKLayers.dll' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ cp 'C:\Users\rob\d3d12SDKLaye ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\rob\...12SDKLayers.dll:FileInfo) [Copy-Item], Unauthorized
   AccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I'm running that Powershell as an Admin. I'm familiar with file permissions on Unix-like systems, but not on Windows. How can I force the file to copy?

Comment: DX12 is built-into Windows 11 and cannot be just replaced.  It’s updated through Windows Update.  Your theory has a lot of problems but you did elevate the PowerShell prompt before you ran that command? How exactly did you determine the file was different?

Comment: Yes to @Ramhound's post.  Is it feasible to reinstall Visual Studio to see if that helps.  Also run DISM / SFC .....   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: I gave a crash dump to Microsoft developers and that is what they told me, that there was a mismatch between d2d12sdklayers.dll and d3d12core.dll. I can see on my other PC that the layers one has a different hash.

Comment: So, what version of Windows 11 is each of the machines running, exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 11 Home, version: 23H2, build: 22631.2715.

Comment: That information should be in the body of your question, not a temporary comment.  How did you determine the hashes of the file were different exactly?  You are running the exact same build of Windows 11 on both machines?

Comment: Yes, that's what it says for versions and build numbers on both machines. They are both new. I used get-filehash in the powershell, which returns a sha256.

Comment: Please edit your question to add all this info to it. This will make your question more clear and complete, very helpful factors in getting good answers.